# Plotting Image on a graph in R

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I have a list of images I would like to loop over and fit within a bounding box (coordinates) in R.

I am able to plot a simple image like so:

```
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE,width = 1, height=1)
df <- data.frame(x=(1:100), 
                 y=(1:100))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=20, xmax=90, ymin=75, ymax=100)
```

Edit: Thanks for all the help! Got it working:

```
library(png)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

img_path <- "C:/flickr_london_new2/"
setwd(img_path)

df <- data.frame(x=(0:0), 
                 y=(0:0))

plot_files <- lapply(list.files(img_path, pattern="*.png"),
                     function(x) list(unlist(strsplit(gsub(".png","",x), "_")),x)

)


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))
for (i in plot_files) {
  bb <- i[[1]]  # Bounding Box
  im_loc <- i[[2]]  # Image
  img <- readPNG(im_loc)
  g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE, width = 1, height=1)
  p <- p + annotation_custom(g, xmin=as.numeric(unlist(bb)[3]),
                                xmax=as.numeric(unlist(bb)[4]),
                                ymin=as.numeric(unlist(bb)[1]),
                                ymax=as.numeric(unlist(bb)[2]))
}
p <- p + ylim(51.46, 51.55) + xlim(-0.22,-0.05)
#P <- p + coord_equal(ratio=122/78)
# Plot
p
```

[Resultant Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPiaS.jpg)

Comment: I would imagine its because your plotting range for the image is very small ... try increasing the xmax, and ymax. [ps typo in your df - x and y are different lengths]

Comment: okay, i just tried your second block of code, using the Rlogo. On plot viewer the plot looks empty, but when exported to pdf and zoomed in , there is a dot where the image is... so yup looks like you need to tweak your annotation ranges.

Comment: Oh I see, the built-in viewer just doesn't go into that much detail I guess. However, I notice that the my axis are not adjusting -> is that because they are not equal as you say? For example if I specify: df <- data.frame(x=(51.471:51.543), 
                 y=(-0.205:-0.049)) ; the graph still plots x from 51 to 52

Comment: 1) I would look at the output of your dataframe call, it is not producing what you think. 2) ggplot tries to choose sensible values for the x and y ranges.. but you can override these (look at `ylim`, `scale_y_continuous`, `coord_cartesian`)

Comment: your plot looks neat... you should add your answer in the answer section, describing what the problem was and what you had to change, as it may help someone in future.